# Searshing for a hadith about arab getting killed in the west at the end

Tags: hadith

I am 100% sure this hadith exist.

The hadith is saying that arabe people living in the west will get killed .

I even remember prophet saw say a word
companion said what is this
he said " arab living in the west will get killed!"

Help me find this hadith .